# issue with flexbox & padding

Tags: html, css

Currently i have what you see in the image below. container 100% browser width. left column has a 100% image. second column has 4 div's controlled with flexbox with 100% images.

http://s10.postimg.org/tlh1nq5zd/sample_1.jpg

the desired effect is what you see below

http://s21.postimg.org/kn82otopz/sample_2.jpg

the padding of div 'items', are making it drop in rows. My CSS might be wrong since I am new to flexbox, But I was under the impression that flexbox could take into consideration the padding/margin of child elements. ( I'm using a 900x528 image just in case anybody is wondering)

```css
#homepage img {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}
#homepage .wrap {
 overflow: hidden;
 padding-right: 2%;
 padding-left: 2%;
 padding-top: 20px;
 padding-bottom: 20px;
 max-width: 1200px;
 margin: auto;
}
#homepage .big {
 float: left;
 width: calc(50% - 10px);

}
#homepage .small {
 float: right;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 justify-content: space-between;
 width: calc(50% - 10px);
}
#homepage .small .item {
 width: 50%;
}
#homepage .small .uno {
 padding: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
}
#homepage .small .dos {
 padding: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
}
#homepage .small .tres {
 padding: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
}
#homepage .small .dos {
 padding: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
}
#homepage .small .cuatro {
 padding: 10px 0px 0px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="homepage">
    
      <div class="wrap">
      
          <div class="big">
          <img src="images/magnus.jpg" />
          </div>
          
          <div class="small">
                    
              <div class="item uno">
                  <img src="images/magnus.jpg" />
              </div>
              
              <div class="item dos">
                  <img src="images/magnus.jpg" />
              </div>
              
              <div class="item tres">
                  <img src="images/magnus.jpg" />
              </div>
              
              <div class="item cuatro">
                  <img src="images/magnus.jpg" />
              </div>
                    
          </div>
      
      </div>
    
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Write down the code like

```css
#homepage img {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}
#homepage .wrap {
 overflow: hidden;
 padding-right: 2%;
 padding-left: 2%;
 padding-top: 20px;
 padding-bottom: 20px;
 max-width: 1200px;
 margin: auto;
}
#homepage .big {
 float: left;
 width: calc(50% - 10px);

}
#homepage .small {
 float: right;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 justify-content: space-between;
 width: calc(50% - 10px);
}
#homepage .small .item {
 width: 50%;
 display: inline-flex;
}
#homepage .small .uno {
 padding: 0;
}
#homepage .small .dos {
 padding: 0;
}
#homepage .small .tres {
 padding: 0;
}
#homepage .small .dos {
 padding: 0;
}
#homepage .small .cuatro {
 padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="homepage">
    
      <div class="wrap">
      
          <div class="big">
          <img src="images/magnus.jpg" />
          </div>
          
          <div class="small">
                    
              <div class="item uno">
                  <img src="images/magnus.jpg" />
              </div>
              
              <div class="item dos">
                  <img src="images/magnus.jpg" />
              </div>
              
              <div class="item tres">
                  <img src="images/magnus.jpg" />
              </div>
              
              <div class="item cuatro">
                  <img src="images/magnus.jpg" />
              </div>
                    
          </div>
      
      </div>
    
    </div>
```

[image]

Comment: I can get it to work without padding on div 'item'. the issue is, there needs to be padding (or margin) on div.item